# image change onclick not working

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, onclick

I want to make a program that changes the image when I click on it.

```js
var image_tracker = "f"

function change() {
  var image = document.getElementById('social');
  if (image_tracker == "f") {
    image.src = "twit.jpg"
    image_tracker = "t"
  }
  if (image_tracker == "t") {
    image.src = "fb.jpeg"
    image_tracker = "f"
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="fb.jpeg" id="social" onclick="change()">
```

I tried the same as the person on youtube did

LINK: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGKXZUGe2sw

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: actually its not working @supra28

Comment: are you getting any errors in your console? Do you even have the images in the same folder? Just saying it doesn't work wont help anyone solve your problem

Comment: first of all change getElementByid to getElementById

Comment: In the 8th line, use `document.getElementById()` ;)

Comment: yes the fb image is being displayed but on clicking the image the image does not change

Comment: "document.getElementByid" should be document.getElementById()

Comment: done document.getElementById still not working @amangpt777

Comment: @AkshatTaneja Posted an answer check if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing your image by the same image as you are using if statement twice instead of else if , do this instead

```js
var image_tracker="f"
function change() {
    var image=document.getElementById('social');
    if (image_tracker=="f") {
        image.src="twit.jpg"
        image_tracker="t"
        image.alt='twit'
    }
    else if (image_tracker=="t") {
        image.src="fb.jpeg"
        image_tracker="f"
        image.alt='fbk'
    } 
}
```

```html
<img src="fb.jpeg" id="social" onclick="change()" alt='fbk'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things stuck out to me here.

1) Syntax issue.  Change your `getElementByid()` method to `getElementById()`

2) Logic issue.  You have two `if` blocks.  The file will switch to the Twitter image upon clicking it, but because `image_tracker` is now set to `t`, it will perform the logic in the second `if` block.  Change the second `if` to an `else if`.